# protocol from TableViewCell to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, class, variables, protocols

I have a table and a custom cell. I get the values ​​from the table and pass them to the cell. From the cell, I have to pass these values ​​to the VC. But if there are these values ​​in the cells, then on VC they are already = nil

```
class CloseMonthTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
 var delegate: StatusCloseMonthDelegate?

@IBAction func setStatus(_ sender: Any) {
  self.delegate?.setStatus(status: 2, empId: empId ?? 0)
  }
}

protocol StatusCloseMonthDelegate: class {
    func setStatus(status: Int, empId: Int)
}
```

**DialocVC**

```
class ApproveDialogView: UIViewController {
        var cellDelegate = CloseMonthTableViewCell()
        var status: Int?
        var empId: Int?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
cellDelegate.delegate = self
  }

 @IBAction func setStatus(_ sender: Any) {
      print(status,empId) // nil and nill Why are they = nil?

      } 
}

extension ApproveDialogView: StatusCloseMonthDelegate {
    func setStatus(status: Int, empId: Int) {
        self.status = status
        self.empId = empId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a little more reading on how to use protocol / delegate pattern.

```
class ApproveDialogView: UIViewController {

    // get rid of this line!
    //var cellDelegate = CloseMonthTableViewCell()
    
    var status: Int?
    var empId: Int?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get rid of this line!
        //cellDelegate.delegate = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func setStatus(_ sender: Any) {
        print(status,empId) // nil and nill Why are they = nil?
        
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you also have an extension for `UITableViewDataSource` and  `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
extension ApproveDialogView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CloseMonthTableViewCell
        
        // normal cell settings

        // set the cell's delegate here!
        cell.delegate = self
        
        return cell
    }
}
```